# MicroSoft Office smart quotes showing up in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ms-office, quotes, apostrophe, smart-quotes

I have a user who is using IE9 and when he enters a single quote from the keyboard into a web form on an application I wrote, it is putting in the fancy curved quotes the MS Word does with the smart quotes enabled. I understand that for Office but why is IE doing that. The result goes into a database record that needs to be searchable and having ’ instead of a ' is buggering up the search.

Anyone else seen that?

Comment: I'm surprised on this question that no one has had any experience with it. Is the Stackoverflow crowd mainly Linux users?